# Used engine oil

Tags: oil, recycle

It is advised to hand over the drained oil to oil recycling centre,what happens to that used oil.
I have seen a few sellers selling very cheap engine oil,do they recycle it and sell it in a new container?
What is the life cycle of a used oil.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about maintenance

Comment: @SolarMike - We get all kinds of questions which do not ***directly*** fit as being "maintenance and repair", but it is directly related to the use and function of an internal combustion engine. We have many such questions here on the site. It is my contention these types of questions are not only ***on topic***, but fit in without issue. The [Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically states: "*Questions **related** to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles...*" Oil is definitely *related*.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 So, by your statement / logic a question about the re-cycling of glass is on-topic as it is used on motor vehicles...

Comment: @SolarMike - If you'd like to take this conversation to [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) to chat about it, I'd be happy to oblige.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to this question will be specific to the locale and the their regulations or laws.

Many places that take the used oil, will sell it to organizations or individuals who use it as fuel for vehicles, burn it in furnaces for heat, or to generate electricity.

According to the American Petroleum Institute, in America;

> The oil you take to a collection center to be recycled saves energy. It
>   can be reprocessed and used in furnaces for heat or in power plants to
>   generate electricity for homes, schools, and businesses. It can also
>   be sent to a refinery that specializes in processing used oil and
>   re-refined into lubricating base oils that can be used to formulate
>   engine oils meeting API specifications.

We would have no idea what your local recycle center does with the oil.

Comment: So, the op needs to do some research in his own country and enlighten us ...But it is not really a maintenance or repair question

Comment: That would be my summation.